# SQL Select Text for multiple foreign keys to lookup table in same row

Tags: sql, join, foreign-keys, lookup

I have a table similar to the following that has a history of changes to an item and holds the old and new value for a status.  The status number is a foreign key to a lookup table that holds the text.  I.e. 1 = 'In Inventory', 2= 'Destroyed' etc..

I want to be able to present this as human readable results and replace the integer keys with the text from the lookup table but I'm not quite sure how to do that as I can't just join on the foreign key.

Demo Database

```
+---------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| ITEM_ID | OLD_STATUS  | NEW_STATUS  | TIMESTAMP  |
+---------+-------------+-------------+------------+
|       1 |          1  | 2           | 2012-03-25 |
|       1 |          2  | 3           | 2013-12-25 |
|       1 |          3  | 4           | 2015-03-25 |
+---------+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `join` on the `status` table multiple times - something like this:

```
select i.item_id, 
    i.old_status, 
    i.new_status,
    i.timestamp,
    s1.statustext,
    s2.statustext
from items i
    join status s1 on i.old_status = s1.statusid
    join status s2 on i.new_status = s2.statusid
```

Comment: oh nice I didn't know I could do that